# Can the ratio test be used to solve the following sequence?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, proof-verification

I am very confident that the ratio test can be used here so I might have a mistake in the calculation

$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{k^{100}}{e^k}$$

Applying the ratio test this becomes:

$$\frac{\frac{(k+1)^{100}}{e^{k+1}}}{\frac{k^{100}}{e^k}}$$

which transforms to

$$\frac{(k+1)^{100}}{e^{k+1}}\frac{e^k}{k^{100}}$$

thus

$$\frac{(k+1)^{100}}{ek^{100}}$$

I am unable to proceed any further

Comment: Now do $=\frac{1}{e}((k+1)/k)^{100}=\frac{1}{e}(1+1/k)^{100}\to\frac{1}{e}$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have that
$$
\begin{gathered}
  \mathop {\lim }\limits_{k \to  + \infty } \frac{{(k + 1)^{100} }}
{{ek^{100} }} = \frac{1}
{e}\mathop {\lim }\limits_{k \to  + \infty } \left( {\frac{{k + 1}}
{k}} \right)^{100}  =  \hfill \\
   \hfill \\
   = \frac{1}
{e}\mathop {\lim }\limits_{k \to  + \infty } \left( {\frac{{k + 1}}
{k}} \right)^{100}  = \frac{1}
{e} \cdot 1^{100} = \frac{1}
{e} < 1 \hfill \\ 
\end{gathered} 
$$
therefore your series is convergent

Comment: Exactly, indeed I also think that the confusion is on that step $$\frac{k+1}{k} \to 1 \implies \left(\frac{k+1}{k}\right)^{n} \to 1^n=1 \quad \forall n$$

Answer (score 2):

Your way is right, to conclude we simply have

$$\frac{(k+1)^{100}}{ek^{100}}=\frac1e \left(\frac{k+1}{k}\right)^{100}\to \frac1e \cdot 1^{100}=\frac1e <1$$

indeed

$$\frac{k+1}{k}=1+\frac1k \to 1 \implies \left(\frac{k+1}{k}\right)^{n} \to 1^n=1 \quad \forall n$$